# Making a CALayer and all the things inside it semi-transparent?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, calayer

How to make a **CALayer** and all the things inside it semi-transparent? That includes all the things drawn with **CoreGraphics** and **CoreText**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `layer.opacity = 0.5` or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Heh, I started reinventing the wheel O.o. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't apply to CoreGraphics elements

Comment: It should apply to everything in the layer. Can you provide more detail as to what you're doing?

Comment: Drawing filled rectangles with CoreGraphics. They stay opaque.